# Python Progress Bar for non-iterable process

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab, tqdm

I'm using this [Notebook](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/blob/master/tutorials/Tutorial16_Document_Classifier_at_Index_Time.ipynb), where section **Apply DocumentClassifier** is altered as below.

**Jupyter Labs**, kernel: `conda_mxnet_latest_p37`.

[tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) is a progress bar wrapper. It seems to work both on `for loops` and in `CLI`. However, I would like to use it on line:

```
classified_docs = doc_classifier.predict(docs_to_classify)
```

This is an iterative process, but under the bonnet.

**How can I apply tqdm to this line?**

---

**Code Cell:**

```
doc_dir = "GRIs/"  # contains 2 .pdfs

with open('filt_gri.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    tags = [current_place.rstrip() for current_place in filehandle.readlines()]


doc_classifier = TransformersDocumentClassifier(model_name_or_path="cross-encoder/nli-distilroberta-base",
                                                task="zero-shot-classification",
                                                labels=tags,
                                                batch_size=2)

# convert to Document using a fieldmap for custom content fields the classification should run on
docs_to_classify = [Document.from_dict(d) for d in docs_sliding_window]

# classify using gpu, batch_size makes sure we do not run out of memory
classified_docs = doc_classifier.predict(docs_to_classify)
```

Comment: If this is not possible, what's an alternative that would work for my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [TDS Article](https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-to-use-progress-bars-in-python-2dc436de81e5); all Python progress bar libraries work with `for loops`. Hypothetically, I could alter the `predict()` function and append there but that's simply too much work.

Note: I'm happy to remove this answer if there is indeed a solution for non-iterablly *"accessible"* processes.